# How to load all file paths into a string array

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load the file paths into a string array (path) but I am stuck.  Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Video/";

String[] videoFileList = {

        path,

};

public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View row = convertView;
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);

        Bitmap bmThumbnail;
        bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFileList[position], Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

        return row;
    }

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, videoFileList));
}
```

}

I am trying to load video paths.  I can load one specific file, but not all the files in the directory.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You should explain what your current results are.

Comment: If my path is to the direct video file, everything works fine.  However the user is going to my putting files into the folder, so there is no way I can know the exact names/how many.  I want to put all of the files' paths present in that folder into a string array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `File.list()`.  Create a `File` object with the path to the files.  `list()` will return an array of `String`.

Example as requested.

```
File pathToFiles = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Video/");

String[] videoFileList = pathToFiles.list();
```

Comment: Could yo provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the files of a given directory, use

```
new File(path).listFiles()
```

or some of the new Java 7 APIs, e.g. :

```
Path dir = new File(path).toPath();     
DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir);
```

Comment: `listFiles()` returns an array of `File` not `String`.